# NPM error 403 during download packages from Azure feed

Tags: node.js, azure, npm

I have Azure feed with npm packages to which I'm connecting using Personal Access Token with Packaging read & write scope. Until recently, everything worked fine, but recently when trying to download packages I get an error:

npm ERR! code E403

npm ERR! 403 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. - GET https://pyvvsblobprodsu6weus63.blob.core.windows.net/...&rscd=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22worker-farm-1.7.0.tgz%22

npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting

npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or

npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.

The token is valid. The download takes place via a proxy but it has been verified that the requests are not blocked. Do you have any ideas what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Even I received the same error code as yours when, I tried to publish the package with same name and tried downloading it.

In order to resolve this error and to download the existing packages from your feed refer the steps below:-

[image]

My **`.npmrc file`**:-

```
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/sid24desai0738/AzureDevops/_packaging/LibWin64/npm/registry/ 
                        
always-auth=true
```

Use the command below to regenerate the credentials for your package:-

```js
vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc //this failed so I used the next command with -force flag. 
vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc -force
```

Then I tried publishing one new package and download one existing package from my feed and both of them were downloaded successfully

```js
npm publish  
npm install myexpressappsiddhesh@0.0.0
npm install expressappp1@1.0.0
```

***Output:-***

[image]

[image]

My package.json after npm install of both the packages from the feed:-

```json
{
  "name": "myexpressappsiddhesh",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "expressappp1": "^1.0.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "myexpressappsiddhesh": "^0.0.0"
  }
}
```

If you are using other machine, Refer the steps in this section with the use of **`PAT token`** with ***Read & write access on Package***:-

[image]

[image]